# DataTable column name include square brackets [name]

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, brackets

I am having a problem with adding a column named "[name] version" to a DataGrid.  If I have something like "[name]" or "version [name]" then escaping, unicode or doubling all work.  There only appears to be a problem when there are characters after the closing bracket.  "[[name] version]" works too but is not what I need.

I am using WPF and C#, this line of code binds the DataTable to the DataGrid.

```
datagrid1.ItemsSource = dataTable1.DefaultView;
```

The error I receive is:

> Syntax error in "PropertyPath 'Syntax
>   error in "Binding.Path '[name]' ...
>   'version'",'".

Comment: Can you change the column name so that it doesn't have this problem?  e.g. 'VersionName'

Comment: @taylonr, no, the company needs the brackets as the brackets and the name within them is a trademarked entity/symbol.

Comment: @Ben... but why do you care that a field in a database is named with a trademarked name?  Call it field1 in the DB and then display '[My Trademarked Bracketed Field] Name'  just my 2 cents, I know you can't always change the field name, but it might be an easy work around

Comment: I am refering to the column heading name on the DataGrid within the WPF program and not a column name within a database table.  I would not be able to get '[My Trademarked Bracketed Field] Name' to work as a column name heading within a DataGrid using WPF.

Comment: My bad, I saw dataGrid and my brain translated to DataSet.

Comment: The brackets are only needed by the database engine's parser. If you have a database field called `[Field]`, it's name is really `Field`. Since the DataGrid is client-side only, try using the name without the brackets.

Comment: You must post code related to binding.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows square brackets or double quotes around column names... can you use double quotes instead?

Comment: Nope, the DataGrid column header name must contain the open and close square brackets.  Note that I am refering to a DataGrid witin a WPF window and not a data column on a database table.

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a helper function which changes the ColumnName property to remove special characters like [] and spaces and I simply leave these characters in the Caption property. So then I bind the Caption to the column header and the ColumnName to the DisplayMemberBinding.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is escape the closing square bracket.

See:

```
   var ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            var dt = ds.Tables.Add();
            dt.Columns.Add("[a[b]c", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Rows.Add(1);
            dt.Rows.Add(2);
            dt.Rows.Add(3);
            dt.Select("[[a[b\\]c]=3").Length.ShouldBe(1);
```